# Sharing MetaData across bounded contexts in Domain-Driven Design (DDD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an odd DDD problem to solve. I have two Bounded Contexts (BC) one for Subscriptions one for Alerts.

The Subscriptions BC has the Alert Type meta data in the form of business rules for what type of alerts a subscriber can subscribe to. Once a subscriber is subscribed to an alert type another system begins to publish these alerts to the Alerts BC and persist. At the time of publish the Alerts BC knows the alert type id but none of its meta data such as alert name and description. That is OK because all that needs to be stored at the time of publish is the Alert with it's Alert Type Id.

However this is where it starts to breakdown for me. There is a requirement to get the user's published alerts and as part of that query it will include meta data on the alert type from the Subscriber BC. Since BC's in general should be atomic this is starting to deviate from a BC's intention.

It does make since, now ordinarily I would think if I need to get a users alerts with the alert type data then I should persist a copy of that alert type data in my Alerts BC at the time of publish. But I am restricted since the caller only wants to send the AlertTypeId and not the extra meta data at the time of publish.

Since querying across BCs is a horrible idea for many reasons. I could think about using a Domain Events solution such as a ESB with an event listener but I just feel that is overkill for meta data. Also wanted to mention this meta data doesn't change often so it could possibly be cached.

Do any DDD experts have any suggestions to tackle this problem? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could consume inter-context operations trough a webservice layer.

Comment: So the application is using multiple web services, however the web service is part of the BC definitions in our case. So I am not sure if that would not be a good approach to fit our needs. 
But that also brings up another topic should the BC include the application and web services or can an application and it's web services as a whole use multiple bounded contexts? At that point the meta data could be represented in a shared kernal and then cached. We could then reference it in both BCs if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with a cache approach for the meta data. The cache manager will be responsible for expiration and re-hydration.